# NoMethodError/Undefined Method While Trying To Use Stripe In Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm implemented Stripe into my app but I'm attempting to move my "Upgrade Membership" option into a partial. I put the code within a partial and attempted to use the partial in my users#show view and the page won't load correctly and it gives me the error listed below. When I visit my charges#new view (which was the default view I set up prior to attempting to move everything over to my users#show view), the view loads and with no problem. But when I throw it in the partial and try to use the partial in my users#show, I get a `NoMethodError/Undefined Method` and I can't seem to figure out why.

Below is the error and my code (I added a comment on the line that's highlighted in the error message). Please let me know if any other code/info needs to be added. Thank you in advance for any help!

**Error**

```
NoMethodError in Users#show
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

<h4>Upgrade To Premium</h4>
    <script class='stripe-button' src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
                                  data-key="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:key] %>" #highlighted line in the error
                                  data-amount=<%= @stripe_btn_data[:amount] %>
                                  data-description="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:description] %>"
                                  data-email="<%= current_user.email %>" >
```

**_form Partial**

```
<% if current_user.premium? %>
  <%= render partial: "charges/downgrade" %>
<% else %>
  <%= form_tag charges_path do %>
    <h4>Upgrade To Premium</h4>
    <script class='stripe-button' src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
                                  data-key="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:key] %>"
                                  data-amount=<%= @stripe_btn_data[:amount] %>
                                  data-description="<%= @stripe_btn_data[:description] %>"
                                  data-email="<%= current_user.email %>" >
    </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Users#show**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2><%= @user.email %></h2>
    <% @wikis.each do |wiki| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to wiki.title, @wiki %></li>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container">
  <%= render partial: "charges/form" %>
</div>
```

I have another partial that I'm using within the partial that I'm having an error with, not sure if it's related but here it is just in case.

**Downgrade Partial**

```
<%= button_to 'Downgrade Membership', user_downgrade_path(current_user), class: 'btn' %>
```

**Charges Controller**

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # Creates a Stripe Customer object, for associating with the charge
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      email: current_user.email,
      card: params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      customer: customer.id, # Note -- this is NOT the user_id in your app
      amount: 15_00,
      description: "Premium Membership - #{current_user.email}",
      currency: 'usd'
    )

    current_user.update_attributes!(role: 'premium')

    flash[:notice] = "Thank you for upgrading to a Premium Membership, #{current_user.email}!"
    redirect_to root_path # or wherever

    # Stripe will send back CardErrors, with friendly messages
    # when something goes wrong.
    # This 'rescue block' catches and displays those errors.
  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:alert] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      @amount = 15_00
      @stripe_btn_data = {
        key: "#{ Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] }",
        description: "BigMoney Membership - #{current_user.email}",
        amount: @amount
      }
    else
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = "You must be signed in to do that."
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being something stupid and easy. I needed to define `@stripe_btn_data` within my `user_controller` since I'm using the partial in a user view.